# How to concatenate, in Tensorflow/Keras, a tensor of shape (None, 1, n) to a tensor of shape (None, None, m) to get (None, None, n+m)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, concatenation, tensor

I am building a model using LSTMs.
The first LSTM layer `lstm1` outputs a Tensor `Out1` of shape `(None, 1, n)` (n is constant, the first dim is the batch size).

I would like to feed a second LSTM `lstm2` by concatenating it `Out1` to a timeseries `ts` of shape `(None, None, m)`.

**How can I concatenate `Out1` to `ts` to get a tensor of shape `(None, None, n+m)` ?**

I have tried to use `keras.layers.concatenate` but I can't get compatible shapes

Comment: If you want to concatenate along one axis, the other axes have to have the same shape to get a full tensor. Otherwise, you have only one value along the first axis for `Out1`, but multiple values along the first axis of the output of `lstm2`. This cannot go together on the same axis.

Comment: This is precisely why I ask this question. I would like to broadcast the value, but it seems tf.concat can't

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf.concat with specifying the dimension, but it will give an extra dimension, which you can remove with tf.squeeze

```
import tensorflow as tf

m = 2
n = 3

# Define placeholder shapes
input_shape_1 = (None, 1, n)
input_shape_2 = (None, None, m)

# Define input tensors
tensor_1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape_1)
tensor_2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape_2)

# Concatenate tensors along the last axis (axis=-1)
concatenated_tensor = tf.concat([tensor_1, tensor_2], axis=-1)
print(concatenated_tensor.shape) # (None, None, 1, 5)

# Remove the extra 1-dimension
concatenated_tensor = tf.squeeze(concatenated_tensor, axis=2)
print(concatenated_tensor.shape) # (None, None, 5)
```